# Best Practices for handling different versions of referenced DLLs in c#

Tags: c#, dll, reference, version, .net-assembly

I have a C# project that references a 3rd party dll.  Users may have different versions of this DLL installed in different locations.

For example if I need to leverage "WonderTool.dll", but it could be installed in:

- %programfiles%\wonderware\v7\bin\plugin\
- %programfiles%\wonderware\v8\bin\plugin\
- %programfiles%\wonderware\v9\bin\plugin\
- %programfiles%\wonderware\v10\bin\plugin\

I cannot include the DLL with my install because I do not know what version of the software will be available on the user's machine.  Is to possible to do a runtime check to see what the latest version that is available and reference it, or is there a best practice I would follow?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If its just one DLL, why not just ship it with your install and install it in with your binaries?